# Integrating Agora SDK Services into Ionic App with Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, agora.io, ionic6, agora

Hello fellow developers,

I'm working on an Ionic v6 app with Angular v14 and I'm exploring the possibility of integrating various services from the Agora SDK, such as text messaging, video calls, audio calls, group video/audio calls, video conferencing, interactive live streaming, and broadcast streaming.

While Agora provides extensive documentation for various platforms, I've been struggling to find specific guidance for integrating these services into an Ionic app with Angular. I've checked the official Agora documentation, but I couldn't find any dedicated information or sdk for Ionic or Angular integration (like they have for react-native etc). Although I am able to find video call package [angular-agora-rtc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-agora-rtc) but there is no package for chat services.

My questions are:

Is it feasible to integrate Agora's services (text messaging, video/audio calls, etc.) into an Ionic app with Angular?

Are there any resources, guides, or examples available outside the official documentation that could help with this integration, especially in chat service?

If Agora's SDK doesn't have specific documentation for Ionic/Angular, would the general JavaScript/TypeScript documentation suffice? Are there any known limitations or considerations?

I tried searching over the internet also searching in agora official documentation.